# Date format in Excel from MySql recordset

Tags: mysql, excel, date-format

I am running a script to fetch data from Mysql, in the select statement I'm using the following format `DATE_FORMAT('2017-01-01 00:00:00', '%m/%d/%Y')`.

However Excel gets the correct value as '01/01/2017', but it doesn't know its a date.

How do I format the value in the select statement so Excel knows its a date with (42736) as the native Excel date number?

[image]?

Comment: How is Excel receiving the data? Are you copying and pasting?  Importing using the import wizard?  Getting it directly from SQL executed in VBA or an external data source?

Comment: Excel is getting the data thru `Set rs = MySqlRS("call myStoredProcedure") .....Sheets("data").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs `

Comment: Does it behave the same way if you use `Cast(DATE_FORMAT('2017-01-01 00:00:00', '%m/%d/%Y') as date)`

Comment: Same format. No difference.

Comment: My research into records sets leads me to believe that poor format handling is a common problem.  Is there a way to run the query without using a record set?